# How to handle errors in AspNet Core Custom ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, model-binding

I´m trying to create a custom model binder that cancels the request when the given data is invalid.

```cs
public sealed class DeploymentIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        string? value = bindingContext
            .ValueProvider
            .GetValue(modelName)
            .FirstValue;

        if (value is null)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        if(DeploymentId.TryParse(value, out var id))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(id);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, $"{value} is not a valid {nameof(DeploymentId)}.");
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("download/{deploymentId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadDeployment(DeploymentId deploymentId)
{
    ...
}
```

I expected to not hit the endpoint if I pass in an invalid DeploymentId.
But instead the method gets called with `deploymentId = null`.

Do I have a wrong expectation/Do I missunderstand how the binders should work?
And if, how would I do it the wright way?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: model binder is just a way of mapping your request data to application model and you can do additional validation of data and fill the modelsate but then you have to check the modelstate in your controller and return response. it does not prevent hitting endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-model-binder-sample). And use url like: https://localhost:7273/authors/index?id=1

result:

[image]